# Uso de substring para cada tipo de situação

Tags: javascript, substring

Possuo uma *variável* com as seguintes informações.

```
var dataEvento = "SEXTA-FEIRA 25 JAN 20H00";
```

Preciso criar 3 *variáveis* diferentes, uma *variável* para *25(Dia)*, *JAN(Mês)* e *20H00(Horário)*.Até o momento ja consegui extrair o horário usando essa função(Me avisem caso esteja de uma maneira incorreta).

```
var horario = dataEvento.substring(dataEvento.lastIndexOf(' ')+1); 
this.horario = horario;
```

Como criar uma função igual a supracitada para o dia e o mês?

Comment: Isso já resolve seu problema: `var r = dataEvento.split(' ')` depois é só recuperar pelo índices: `this.data = r[1]; this.mes = r[2]; this.horario = r[3];`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) que "quebra" uma string em vários pedaços (um array com N elementos), basta definir qual será o separador.

Ex:

```
"abc 123 def 456".split(' ');  // ['abc', '123', 'def', '456']
```

No seu caso, se aplicado o método acima teríamos:

```
"SEXTA-FEIRA 25 JAN 20H00".split(' ');
// ['SEXTA-FEIRA', '25', 'JAN', '20H00']
```

A partir disso é só criar as variáveis desejadas e ignorar o primeiro elemento.

```
let result = ['SEXTA-FEIRA', '25', 'JAN', '20H00']
dia = result[1]
mes = result[2]
horario = result[3]
```

Se compatibilidade não for um problema, você também pode usar [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) do ECMAScript2015:

```
let [_, dia, mes, horario] = ['SEXTA-FEIRA', '25', 'JAN', '20H00']
```

---

Juntando tudo:

```
const extractData = stringEvento => {
    let [_, dia, mes, hora] = stringEvento.split(' ')
    return {dia, mes, hora}
}
```

---

Exemplo completo:

```js
const extractData = stringEvento => {
    let [_, dia, mes, hora] = stringEvento.split(' ')
    return {dia, mes, hora}
}

let sessoes = [
    {
        codEvento: 29,
        descricao: "SEXTA-FEIRA 25 JAN 20H00",
        atual: true
    }, {
     codEvento: 30, 
        descricao: "SÁBADO 26 JAN 21H00", 
        atual: false
    }, {
     codEvento: 31, 
        descricao: "DOMINGO 27 JAN 20H00", 
        atual: false
    }
]

// Atualizar sessoes com a data alterada
sessoes = sessoes.map(evento => {
    evento.data = extractData(evento.descricao)
    return evento
})

console.log(sessoes)
```

Comment: Não muda nada, você só precisa preparar seu código antes. Vou fazer um exemplo e te mando o link. Aguarde um minuto

Comment: Formulei mal a pergunta, eu recebo esse array no caso, não como `['SEXTA-FEIRA', '25', 'JAN', '20H00']` , mas sim como nesse exemplo https://imgur.com/a/GkZqw7r

Comment: Você pode usar um `for` ou `Array.map()` para aplicar a lógica para cada um dos elementos do array. [Aqui fiz um exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/kyo7Ldun/) que percorre o array e cria uma nova propriedade `data` dentro de cada elemento do array com o valor convertido.

Comment: Atualizei a questão com um exemplo usando arrays

Comment: Funcionando perfeitamente, ótimos exemplos!

Answer (score 6):

Podes usar o `.split()` como o [fernandosavio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/358263/129) também sugeriu:

```js
const [, dia, mes, hora] = 'SEXTA-FEIRA 25 JAN 20H00'.split(' ');
console.log(dia); // 25
console.log(mes); // JAN
console.log(hora); // 20H00
```

Ou podes usar uma RegExp para extrair o resultado:

```js
const regExp = /[^\d]+(\d+)\s([a-z]+)\s(\d+H\d+)/i;
const string = 'SEXTA-FEIRA 25 JAN 20H00';
const [, dia, mes, hora] = string.match(regExp);
console.log(dia); // 25
console.log(mes); // JAN
console.log(hora); // 20H00
```

A RegExp explicada seria:

- `[^\d]+` - qualquer caracter que não numero, 1 ou mais vezes
- `(\d+)` - um numero, uma ou mais vezes, com captura (para poder usar depois)
- `\s` - espaço em branco
- `([a-z]+)` - uma letra, uma ou mais vezes, com captura
- `/i` - letras grandes e pequenas